# using macros for mixin traits in Scala

Tags: scala, macros

Let say that I have these traits:

```
object Sample14 {

  import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context
  import scala.language.experimental.macros

  trait A
  trait B extends A
  trait C extends A
  trait D

  class ToMix {
    def mixTraits(x: A, y: D) = macro implMixTraits
  }

  def implMixTraits(c: Context)(x: c.Expr[A], y: c.Expr[D]): c.Expr[Any] = {/*...*/}

}
```

How I can use macros to mix traits. I used a couple of resources that are available but I really cannot get how if I can mix them in this way? Thanks for any idea, or suggestion!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The question is really unclear.

Comment: @Imm, I started few weeks before with macros (actually, when you replied in one of my questions, when I was worried about the mixin order of traits), and I hoped that macros may help me to find an idea in my project (a kind of research work) ... anyway, this question is just from the curiosity. I though, if I write `val mxd = toMix.mixTraits(C, D)` then they can be mixed.

Comment: again, *what do you actually want to happen*? What do you mean by "they can be mixed"?

Comment: @Imm , I want to generate in some way the mixin (speaking strictly) through using macros.

Comment: What is a "mixin (speaking strictly)"? I'm beginning to sound like a broken record, but *what do you actually want to happen*? Like, show some code that calls `mixTraits`.

Comment: @Imm, it's so trivial what code can require it; so don't repeat yourself :) bcz actually I think I have a version of its sol. Thanks